# Can the Lotus Notes Browser remember standard webpage login credentials?

Tags: browser, authentication, lotus-notes, remember-me

We have a client who uses a website we have created. The requires the standard username/password combination to access site contents.

In *IE*, *FF* and *Chrome* the browser offers to remember the login credentials, but our client is using some built in *Lotus Notes* browser and it doesn't seem to offer this service. Since the *Lotus Notes* browser seems to be a wrapper on *IE*, it might be sufficient to clear the login-cache in the browser.

Our client is not a superuser in any way and we do not have access to a *Lotus Notes* system. We don't want to clear the login-cache in the browser if it doesn't help and causing our client to loose any existing login-credentials.

**Question 1**: Does anyone know if the *Lotus Notes* browser can remember login credentials?

If yes:
**Question 2**: Can anyone confirm that clearing the login-cache in the browser force it to offer to remember the login credentials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using R6.0.4, so this is definitely outdated, but I do not get a prompt to save a password.  It's possible a newer version offers that capability, but my guess is IBM is investing very little in making the wrapped IE browser or the Notes-internal browser work much better.

As an alternative, Notes can be set to use Internet Explorer or Firefox as its browser when it launches links.  That can be managed in the location document.  In v6, that can be edited by clicking the location name in the bottom status bar, and then selecting "Edit Current..."  In there you can select what internet browser is being used.

If there's a need to maintain that setting on the user's notes client, then another work around is to create a duplicate of his/her primary location document (usually the Office one), and change it say "Office - Firefox" for example.  That location document can have all the same settings except the browser preference.  Then when they need to work on the site, they can easily switch locations first.